# Android прочитать записанный в память список

Tags: java, android

Ребят получил список данных через ретрофит, сохранил его во внутреннюю память, и не пойму как сделать что бы читало его, то есть при первом запуске скачивает данные через интернет, а потом без интернета уже считывало что сохранилось.

Запись

```
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                try {
                    // записал файл "name.ser" в Download
                    FileOutputStream fos =
                            new FileOutputStream(
                                    new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "name.ser")
                            );
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    os.writeObject(countries);
                    os.close();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File has been written");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File didn't write");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Вы не записали список в файл. countries.toString() не конвернирует список в строку. Вот вам запрос в гугл, как записать `ArrayList` в файл
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20write%20arraylist%20to%20file

Comment: изменил, запись нашел, но считать не получается

Comment: А как вы пробовали считать? Вы же не показали.

Comment: Может стоит использовать базу данных, а перед стартом активити проверять количество записей в базе и если их 0, то загружать данные?

Comment: я только учусь и базу данных еще не проходил, по этому тут важно локально данные, я не пробовал считать, в гугле нашел вот такой способ записи, проверил файл лежит на карте, а вот как считать там не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы записываете в файл при помощи `ObjectOutputStream`, то логично читать его `ObjectInputStream`ом .
Пример зеркально по Вашему коду:

```
 if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
    try {
        // прочитал файл "name.ser" из Download
        FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "name.ser"));
        ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fIS);
        countries = oIS.readObject();
        oIS.close();
        Log.v("MyApp","File has been readed");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("MyApp","File didn't readed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, вроде работает спасибо, немного подправил, добавил лист в чтении объекта.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сохранять данные в `SharedPreference`:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("countries", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    // write
    editor.putInt("KEY_SIZE", countries.length);
    for(int i=0; i<countries.length; i++)
        editor.putString("KEY_" + String.valueOf(i), countries[i]);
    editor.commit();

    // read
    int size = preferences.getInt("KEY_SIZE", -1);
    String[] countries = null;
    if(size != -1){
        countries = new String[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            countries[i] = preferences.getString("KEY_" + String.valueOf(i), "default");
        }
    }
```